# How did my existence is in place at first? Why am there as me and not as anyone?

Tags: atma

This question could be a tricky one and may look confused but it's not so. Why my own existence is confined to "me" and why I did not exist as God or some other being? Why my existence came as my individual soul and not any other soul? Can u get my question?  If we're Lords one part of energy, why my existence consciousness was not Lords superior energy? In general, what is existence?  Why I am not some other soul? Why my existence was not as deities? Why my existence is as individual Atman and not superior to it? Why am as Jiva? What is basis of existence? "I" here can fall down to lower realms or go to spiritual world. So here "I" is between spiritual and material. So who am I? From this we can understand Jiva we are between spiritual and material. So Atman is a state. So who am I and we? And why we are existing and am existing as me and you and not you and me?

This is a different aspect of the question. It's not who am I, its why am I , the reason behind why am I this and why am not that. Or in nature, aside God, everyone evolved from Jivas?

Comment: No this is more than who am I. Because see I have already talked about we souls. This is about how we souls are existing and why we our conscious are with souls and not with any other.

Comment: That's why first we need to qualify ourselves to understand and realize this transcendental knowledge. We need to live a life as an offering to God and only then, the truth will reveal to us. Otherwise, everything will just be a belief and we'll ruin our lives without Atman Jnana and Brahma Jnana

Comment: Falling down has been easy, but going to place from where we fell, is difficult because of powerful influence of Kaliyuga & the Mahamaya. Only true surrender to supreme Lord, or to Guru or to a person who lives beyond these conditioned life, alone can take us across this ocean of Samsara.

Comment: you have too many questions in 1 question. separate your questions into different questions.

Comment: There are no answer to such questions "Why this ... why that". You are what you are.

Comment: This Q is not a duplicate.